# SQL insert into AND update

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-into

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to update a table and insert data into another table at the same time.

Like

```
UPDATE table1
SET column4=true
AND INSERT into table2
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM table 1
WHERE column1="peter"
;
```

Comment: Your Postgres version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Postgres 9.1 or later you can use something like:

```
WITH source AS (UPDATE table1
                SET column4=true
                WHERE column1='peter'
                RETURNING column1, column2, column3)
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM source;
```

Comment: If you're trying to find out more, search for "writeable common table expression". It's a PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: While it's all in one statement it's not necessarily going to see the same data from the same moment in `read committed`. Consider `repeatable read` or greater isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute multiple statements inside a transaction, so it will still be an atomic change to your data.

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE table1
SET column4=true;

INSERT into table2
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM table 1
WHERE column1="peter";

COMMIT;
```

If for whatever reason the insert fails, the entire transaction will fail, and the changes will be backed out, including the update that was executed before the insert statement.

Comment: In Postgres 9.1+ you can do any number of DML in a single statement using CTE.

Comment: It's atomic in the sense of becoming visible at commit, but if you're in `read committed` mode then the two statements can still see different data if someone else commits in between them. I'd use at least `repeatable read` isolation, preferably `serializable`.

Comment: I meant atomic as in, either the whole transactions succeeds or fails. I mean, that would be the purpose of trying to write two DML statements into one, right?